# psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Tags: amazon-redshift, airflow

I try to get test query to AWS RedShift from AWS Managed AirFlow:

QUERY:

```
AWS_GET_DATA_FROM_REDSHIFT = """('SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables;')"""

stage_data_from_redshift_to_s3 = FromRedshiftToS3TransferOperator(
    task_id=f'Stage_unload_{SCHEMA}_{TABLE}_from_redshift_to_s3_{S3_BUCKET}',
    dag=dag,
    table=TABLE,
    s3_bucket=S3_BUCKET,
    s3_prefix=f'{SCHEMA}_{TABLE}',
    select_query=AWS_GET_DATA_FROM_REDSHIFT,
    unload_options=['CSV']
)

class FromRedshiftToS3TransferOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
        Executes an UNLOAD command to s3 as a CSV with headers

        :param schema: reference to a specific schema in redshift database
        :type schema: str
        :param table: reference to a specific table in redshift database
        :type table: str
        :param s3_bucket: reference to a specific S3 bucket
        :type s3_bucket: str
        :param s3_key: reference to a specific S3 key
        :type s3_key: str
        :param redshift_conn_id: reference to a specific redshift database
        :type redshift_conn_id: str
        :param aws_conn_id: reference to a specific S3 connection
        :type aws_conn_id: str
        :param verify: Whether or not to verify SSL certificates for S3 connection.
            By default SSL certificates are verified.
            You can provide the following values:

            - ``False``: do not validate SSL certificates. SSL will still be used
                     (unless use_ssl is False), but SSL certificates will not be
                     verified.
            - ``path/to/cert/bundle.pem``: A filename of the CA cert bundle to uses.
                     You can specify this argument if you want to use a different
                     CA cert bundle than the one used by botocore.
        :type verify: bool or str
        :param unload_options: reference to a list of UNLOAD options
        :type unload_options: list
        :param autocommit: If set to True it will automatically commit the UNLOAD statement.
            Otherwise it will be committed right before the redshift connection gets closed.
        :type autocommit: bool
        :param include_header: If set to True the s3 file contains the header columns.
        :type include_header: bool
    """

    ui_color = '#8EB6D4'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 table,
                 s3_bucket,
                 s3_prefix,
                 select_query,
                 redshift_conn_id='redshift',
                 aws_conn_id='aws_credentials',
                 unload_options=tuple(),
                 autocommit=False,
                 include_header=False,
                 *args, **kwargs):
        super(FromRedshiftToS3TransferOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.table = table
        self.s3_bucket = s3_bucket
        self.s3_prefix = s3_prefix
        self.select_query = select_query
        self.redshift_conn_id = redshift_conn_id
        self.aws_conn_id = aws_conn_id
        self.unload_options = unload_options
        self.autocommit = autocommit
        self.include_header = include_header

        if self.include_header and 'HEADER' not in [uo.upper().strip() for uo in self.unload_options]:
            self.unload_options = list(self.unload_options) + ['HEADER', ]

    def execute(self, context):
        aws_hook = AwsHook("aws_credentials")
        credentials = aws_hook.get_credentials()
        redshift_hook = PostgresHook("redshift")

        self.log.info(f'Preparing to stage data from {self.select_query} to {self.s3_bucket}/{self.s3_prefix}...')

        unload_query = """
                    UNLOAD {select_query}
                    TO 's3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_prefix}/{table}_'
                    with credentials
                    'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key={secret_key}'
                    {unload_options};
                """.format(select_query=self.select_query,
                           s3_bucket=self.s3_bucket,
                           s3_prefix=self.s3_prefix,
                           table=self.table,
                           access_key=credentials.access_key,
                           secret_key=credentials.secret_key,
                           unload_options='\n\t\t\t'.join(self.unload_options))

        self.log.info(f'{credentials.access_key}')
        self.log.info(f'{credentials.secret_key}')
        self.log.info('Executing UNLOAD command...')
        redshift_hook.run(unload_query, self.autocommit)
        self.log.info("UNLOAD command complete.")
```

And get an error:

```
[2021-08-17 10:40:50,186] {{taskinstance.py:1150}} ERROR - Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/ownoperators/aws_from_redshift_to_s3_operator.py", line 95, in execute
    redshift_hook.run(unload_query, self.autocommit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py", line 175, in run
    cur.execute(s)
psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is generated by Redshift and in most cases it is when your query uses a leader-node only function (such as generater_series() - there are a number of these).  Look at your select_query code and check if the functions called are valid on compute nodes (run the query in a workbench).  Happy to help if you post the query.  The issue is the SQL, not the code you posted.

The root of the issue is that leader node information is needed by the compute nodes during execution and this route isn't supported. There can be several causes for this and each has work-arounds.